# If $\text E\left[1_F\int_a^bf(X_{s+t})\:{\rm d}t\right]=\text E\left[1_F\int_a^b(κ_tf)(X_s)\right]$, then $X$ is Markov with transition semigroup $κ$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$;
- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-adapted process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$;
- $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$.

Suppose we want to show that $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-Markov with transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$; i.e. $$\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F_s\right]=(\kappa_tf)(X_s)\tag1$$ for all bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$ and $s,t\ge0$.

> Why is it sufficient to show that, for fixed $s\ge0$, $F\in\mathcal F_s$ and bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$, the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\mathcal B([0,\infty))$, defined by \begin{align}\mu((a,b])&:=\operatorname E\left[1_F\int_a^bf(X_{s+t})\:{\rm d}t\right];\\\nu((a,b])&:=\operatorname E\left[1_F\int_a^b(\kappa_tf)(X_s)\:{\rm d}t\right]\end{align} for $0\le a<b$, coincide?

We may note that the Laplace transform of $\nu$ is given by \begin{equation}\begin{split}\mathcal L_\nu(\lambda)&=\int\nu({\rm d}t)e^{-t\lambda}\\&=\operatorname E\left[1_F\int_0^\infty e^{-t\lambda}(\kappa_tf)(X_s)\right]\\&=\operatorname E\left[1_F\left(\tilde R_\lambda f\right)(X_s)\right],\end{split}\tag2\end{equation} where $$\tilde R_\lambda f:=\int_0^\infty e^{-t\lambda}\kappa_tf\:{\rm d}t$$ for all $\lambda\ge0$.

> Most probably we need further assumptions, but ignoring rigor for a moment, we may note the following: If $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ denotes the infinitesimal generator of $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ (considered as a (contractive) semigroup on the space of bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable (maybe even continuous; I don't know if this matters) functions $E\to\mathbb R$ equipped with the supremum norm), we know (from general semigroup theory) that the resolvent $R_\lambda(A)$ for $\lambda\in\rho(A)$ is equal to $\tilde R_\lambda$ (see [Theorem 2.12 here](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Ekondrat/course/osg2.pdf#page=14) and note that we can take $\omega=0$).

Comment: If $\int\limits_\mathrm{A} f = \int\limits_\mathrm{A} g$ for all measurable $\mathrm{A},$ then $f = g$ almost surely. Note that $\int\limits_\cdot f$ and $\int\limits_\cdot g$ are (signed) measures, so the usual way applies (i.e. suffices to show that both signed measures coincide in a suitable $\pi$-system). So, you are considering the integral to be $\mathbf{E} \otimes \int\limits_{\mathrm{A}},$ on the product space, and it seems a suitable $\pi$-system will be $F \times [a, b],$ for $F \in \mathscr{F}_s$ and $a \leq b$.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thank you for your comment. Wouldn't this yield $1_A(\omega)f(X_{s+t}(\omega))=(\kappa_tf)(X_s(\omega))$ for almost all $(\omega,t)\in\Omega\times[s,\infty)$ instead?

Comment: I was thinking of writting your integrals as $\int_A \mathbf{E}(\cdots) = \int_A \mathbf{E} (\cdots),$ then the inner integrals coincide.

Comment: @WilliamM. In order to do this, we need to $(\omega,t)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is measurable (since we need Fubini)

Comment: @WilliamM. Moreover, this should only yield $\operatorname E[1_Af(X_{s+t})]=\operatorname E[1_A(\kappa_tf)(X_s)]$ (and since $A$ was arbitrary, $\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F_s\right]=(\kappa_tf)(X_s)$) **for almost all** $t$. I think we need continuous dependence on $t$ to conclude that it holds **for all** $t$.

Answer (score 2):

Unless mistaken from the definition of $\mu$ and $\nu$ we have for any $0<a<b$ :
$$\mu((a,b])=E\left[1_F\int_a^bf(X_{s+t})\:{\rm d}t\right]=E\left[1_F.E\left[\int_a^bf(X_{s+t})\:{\rm d}t|\mathcal{F}_s\right]\right]=\nu[(a,b])= E\left[1_F\int_a^b(\kappa_tf)(X_s)\:{\rm d}t\right]$$

Now $(\kappa_tf)(X_s)$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable and from a.s. unicity of conditional expectation with respect to  $\mathcal{F}_s$ you get almost surely :
$$\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F_s\right]=(\kappa_tf)(X_s)$$
Now you can finish the argument as the interval $(a,b]$ is indeed a $\pi$-system as suggested by William M.  so that it's true for $\sigma((a,b] b>a>0)= \mathcal B(\mathbb R^+)$ (after completion unless mistaken)

Comment: How do you get $\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F_s\right]=(\kappa_tf)(X_s)$ almost surely **for all** $t\in(a,b]$? (See my comments below the question.)

Comment: We should only get $\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F_s\right]=(\kappa_tf)(X_s)$ almost surely for almost all $t$.

Comment: Unless mistaken by a.s. unicity of conditional expectation as $(\kappa_tf)(X_s)$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable.

Comment: Yes, it's clear to me that (for fixed $s,t\ge0$) $\operatorname E[1_Af(X_{s+t})]=\operatorname E[1_A(\kappa_tf)(X_s)]$ for all $A\in\mathcal F_s$ implies $\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal F_s\right]=(\kappa_tf)(X_s)$. However, I think that $\mu=\nu$ only implies that (for fixed $s\ge0$) $\operatorname E[1_Af(X_{s+t})]=\operatorname E[1_A(\kappa_tf)(X_s)]$ **for almost all** $t$ for all $A\in\mathcal F_s$

Comment: Ok so take a representation of the a.s. equivalence class of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ then on the negligible set (for Lebesgue measure) where they do not coincide set their values to 0  for both those representative and now they are equal on every set (and every t not only a.s.), and are both in the representative a.s. class of each measure. Now you can apply the argument above right ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it took me a while to come back to this problem. What we have shown is $$\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t});A\right]=\operatorname E\left[(\kappa_tf)(X_s);A\right]$$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)\setminus N$, where $N$ is a Lebesgue-null set. However, $N$ does depend on $A$, which is preventing us from the conclusion you've suggested.